# React bootstrap form not rendering spaces in text inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react bootstrap components. I have form elements that follow this sort of structure:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      show: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this)
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this)
  }

  handleShow () {
    this.setState({ show: true })
  }

  handleClose () {
    this.setState({ show: false })
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
  <div>
    <Button bsStyle='success' onClick={this.handleShow}>Add New</Button>
    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Add New</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
      <form>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel className='form-input'>1. Provide Name</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl onChange={this.handleChange} className='form-input' type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name' value={this.state.name} />
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I type in the text input it removes the spaces e.g. I type 'hello world' but it renders 'helloworld'

I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Edit: I forgot to mention the form is rendering within a bootstrap modal, I don't know if that's what's causing the issue? I've just refactored my code and updated my example snippet to match.

Problem solved: The issue solved itself when we separated the button out so the button was not part of the component and we just return the modal.

Comment: working fine plz check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scfxhf

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel,  FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap'
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <FormGroup>
          <ControlLabel className='form-input'>1. Provide Name</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl onChange={this.handleChange} className='form-input' type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name' value={this.state.name} />
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```